# Batch script to find a value in the first column of text file based on the parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file links.txt:

```
1 a b c
21 b d
14 c j k l
5 d r e
```

test.bat 1:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('findstr /b "%*" links.txt') do (
echo %%c
)
```

I passed "1" as parameter to test.bat and expected output is "1 a b c". But it is displaying all the rows which is beginning with "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is "find all of the lines in the file that `/b` (begin) `1` (passed in as a parameter).

You need

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('findstr /b /c:"%1 " links.txt') do (
```

as the syntax of `findstr` requires `/c:"find this string" /c:"or this string"` to find an exact string containing spaces - `"find this string"` will find `find` *or* `this` *or* `string`

You could process your input-parameter string like:

```
SET "params= %*"
SET "params=%params: = " /c:"% ""
SET "params=%params:~2%"
findstr /b %params% ....
```

OR perhaps use

```
findstr /b /g:"afilename" ...
```

where `afilename` contains your required strings one to a line **with the spaces appended as required**. Note that many editors will drop trailing spaces by default.

---

For the example case in the comment...

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET "params= %*"
SET "params=%params: = " /c:"% ""
SET "params=%params:~2%"
echo the params string is %params%
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('findstr /b /L %params% links.txt') do (
echo %%c
)
```

`params` is assigned the value of the command-tail. Each space is then replaced by `" /c:"` and `"` appended to the end. Then only those characters after the second are used.

Comment: Hi @Magoo, in case if i pass "1 21 14" as parameters what should i include in the above code?